# Building a custom Node-RED image

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, node-red

I would like to make my own Node-RED docker image so when I start it the flows are loaded and Node-RED is ready to go.

The flow I want to load is placed in a 'flows.json' file. And when I import it manually via the interface it works fine.

The Node-RED documentation for docker suggests the following line for starting Node-RED with a custom flow

```
$ docker run -it -p 1880:1880 -e FLOWS=my_flows.json nodered/node-red-docker
```

However when I try to do this the flow ends up empty.

I suspect this has to do something with the fact that the flow I'm trying to load is using the 'node-red-node-mongodb' plug-in, which is not installed by default.

How can I build a Node-RED image where the 'node-red-node-mongodb' is already installed?

If anymore information is required please ask.

**UPDATE**

I made the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM nodered/node-red-docker

RUN npm install node-red-node-mongodb
```

Then I build it with:

```
docker build -t testenvironment/nodered .
```

And started it with:

```
docker run -d -p 1880:1880 -e FLOWS=flows.json --name node-red testenvironment/nodered
```

But when I go to the Node-RED interface there is no flow. Also I don't see the MongoDB node in the sidebar.

Comment: The docker file in your update works just fine, the mongo nodes will be found in the storage group. The `-e FLOWS=flows.json` just names the flow file within the container, if you want to add an existing flow to the image then you need to add an extra line to the Dockerfile `ADD flows.json /data/flows.json` to copy the file into the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://nodered.org/docs/platforms/docker#customising) on the Node-RED site includes instructions for how to customise a Docker image and add extra nodes. You can either do it by logging into the existing image using `docker exec` and installing the node by hand with `npm`

```
# Open a shell in the container
docker exec -it mynodered /bin/bash

# Once inside the container, npm install the nodes in /data
cd /data
npm install node-red-node-mongodb
exit

# Restart the container to load the new nodes
docker stop mynodered
docker start mynodered
```

Else you can extend the image by creating your own Docker file:

```
FROM nodered/node-red-docker
RUN npm install node-red-node-mongodb
```

And then build it with

```
docker build -t mynodered:<tag> .
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I still didn't quite figure it out. Could you take a look the updated question?